# Mongodb monitoring using mikoomi plugin of zabbix is not rendering any data

Tags: monitoring, mongodb, zabbix

I'm using mikoomi plugin https://code.google.com/p/mikoomi/wiki/03 to monitor mongo db, in that there is shell script which is calling php script and returning 0 to zabbix and parallely writing a data file and log file in /tmp/ directory.

Now my question is how zabbix is reading that data/log file and how keys are fetching information from that file? I need to debug this because zabbix is not rendering any data.
How do I set this up correctly?

Format of data file is as follows:

---

```
<Mongo Hostname> mem_virtual 39484
<Mongo Hostname> connections_current 34
<Mongo Hostname> mem_resident 1018
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered same question in SO, copying here.

Mikoomi script is using [zabbix_sender](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.2/manpages/zabbix_sender) utility to notify zabbix server about the data collected.

```
exec("zabbix_sender -vv -z 127.0.0.1 -i $data_file_name 2>&1", $log_file_data) ;
```

Zabbix server will read the key values from data file and update the db.

Which OS are you using? Check for `selinux` policy related errors. If `selinux` policies are enabled in your server, disable and check whether data file is getting updated.

For checking `selinux` policy enable/disable, run below command

```
getenforce
```

If the output is `Enforcing` then `selinux` policies are enabled. Disable using following command.

```
setenforce 0
```

And again run `getenforce` to check whether the output is `Permissive`.